# How to expand on a class template integer list?

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

So I've been trying to learn more about c++ metaprogramming and I'm stuck in trying to design a tuple of varying length arrays.

The idea of what I want to do is something like this:

```
CustomArrays<float, 3, 2> arrays;
```

The first argument '`float`' is the type of data the arrays will store. The arguments following are the lengths of each array. I can make a struct like this that takes these arguments:

```
template <typename T, uint... As> struct CustomArrays {};
```

I know that if I only took one argument instead of a list I could store the array like this:

```
template <typename T, uint A> struct CustomArrays { T data[A]; };
```

This is what I want but with the expanded subclasses, similar to what the tuple could do. I'm thinking something along this:

```
template <typename T, uint A> struct CustomArrays {};

template <typename T, uint A, uint... As>
struct CustomArrays : CustomArrays<T, As...> {
    T data[A];
};
```

The idea is to have this expand like this:

```
struct CustomArrays<float, 2, 3> : CustomArrays<float, 3> {
    float data[2];
}

struct CustomArrays<float, 3> : CustomArrays {
    float data[3];
}

struct CustomArrays {}
```

This of course doesn't compile since we redeclare the same struct with different template parameters. My question is how can I achieve the desired outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `std::array` instead custom arrays or old C-style arrays.

If you want a variadic list of `std::array`, you can use `std::tuple` and write something like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Dims>
struct CustomArrays
 { std::tuple<std::array<T, Dims>...> data; };
```

You can also try using C-style arrays

```
template <typename T, std::size_t ... Dims>
struct CustomArrays
 { std::tuple<T[Dims]...> data; };
```

but I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, I'm actually surprised as to how simple it is to implement this using the standard. Thanks!

Comment: @Belfer4 - if (when) you can, use C++17: with fold expressions the use of variadic arguments is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

You might be looking for something like this:

```
template <typename T, uint... As> struct ArrayType;

template <typename T>
struct ArrayType<T> {
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, uint A, uint... As>
struct ArrayType<T, A, As...> {
    typedef typename ArrayType<T, As...>::type type[A];
};

template <typename T, uint... As>
struct CustomArrays {
  typename ArrayType<T, As...>::type data;
  // CustomArrays<float, 3, 2>::data is of type float[3][2]
};
```

Comment: This is an interesting design, but it is not what I need. This makes a 3x2 array where I just want two arrays in contiguous memory of length 3 and then 2, i.e. float[3]; float[2];. Thanks for the alternative approach tho!

Comment: `template <typename T, uint... As> struct CustomArrays { std::tuple<T[As]...> data; };` then?

Comment: Yes, this works. But I think this is essentially the equivalent of the first answer.